# Visual Studio 2015 Find in Files not remembering file types or locations

Tags: visual-studio, find, visual-studio-2015

I rely on the Find in Files dialog in Visual Studio a great deal. (Sometimes Intellisense/Resharper just don't cut it.) Since upgrading to 2015, I've noticed that the dialog doesn't remember my custom "Look in" paths or "Look at these file types" lists between sessions.

If I close my solution and VS instance, then reopen, I have to enter my custom path and file types again. Huge waste of time. Has anyone run else run into this? Any workaround? 2013 used to remember this stuff.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.00081
Installed Version: Professional
```

Comment: I have Visual Studio Enterprise. I tried and in my case it remembers both values across restarts.

Comment: @LukkhaCoder It would be strange if the issue was specific to Professional vs Enterprise edition, but I guess it's possible. A co-worker was able to reproduce the issue on his VS 2015 Pro.

Comment: Did you install any of the VS 2015 pre-release versions? I installed the RC, then uninstalled it before I installed the RTM version. Now I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: @probackpacker Nope, clean install of VS 2015 Pro after release.

Comment: @JordanRieger Bummer, I was hoping that we might be able to isolate the scenarios that cause this bug. In the mean time I've submitted a "frown" via Visual Studio. If I receive any feedback, I will post it here.

Comment: I have the same issue. I have 2013 Premium and 2015 Professional installed side by side. Closing and reopening 2015 clears my custom custom "look in" paths, whereas 2013 retains them.

Comment: Does anyone know if update 1 fixed this issue? (I have not installed Update 1 as a colleague installed it and it bricked his install, so I'm wary.) For the record, I have this issue with VS2015 Enterprise. It also have 2013 Premium installed. Another noteworthy issue with my 2015 install is that it didn't put any program shortcuts in my start menu. The menu item is there, but it only contains Feedback Client, Tools and SDK.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman I just installed Update 1, and it didn't help :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this today. After much searching I found a [post on the visual studio forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0be2d616-6d79-470d-9747-b3b50133b434/save-folder-set-in-find-and-replace-dialog?forum=visualstudiogeneral) somehow. This pointed me towards ReSharper. This directed me towards a workaround.

1. Start visual studio in safe mode with the command line argument `/SafeMode`
2. Create the folder sets you want for searching
3. Restart visual studio not in safemode

Once I had restarted all my created custom searches remained, and the registry values were created. This might not work in the specific case, but this worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me. Woohoo!

Comment: Note: `/SafeMode` seems to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 8):

I've never had any problems with it not remembering my settings, but I imagine that you could run a custom registry modifier to add the appropriate keys, you could make sure your settings are always pristine. The custom search information is stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Find`.

The file types are stored in a string key called `Filter` with whatever you would normally input into the custom file type category in the VS search window. For example searching for only `.cs` and `.txt` files you would put `*.cs;*.txt`.

The folders are located in a string key called `Query` with values such as `C:\Folder1;C:\Folder2`. However, it's behavior seems a little weird. You have change the value of `Query` and a `Query+integer` value (i.e. `Query0`) to the same value to have it appear in Visual Studio.

If you just run a script to modify the above values to the files types/folder locations you want, that should work.

Comment: Interesting, let me look into this when I get back to work on Monday.

Comment: @Ringli it seems that Visual Studio is not respecting those values for me. It will ignore them when it starts, and when it exists, it will replace them with new values corresponding to the most recent search, but ignore them when it starts again. I also tried disaling ReSharper, but that didn't help.

Comment: Are neither the file types nor the folder locations working? If so, are you just getting the defaults? (i.e. Entire Solution?)

Comment: @Ringli Yes, I'm getting the defaults.

Comment: Maybe you can try: Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings. Obviously, before you do this you should export your settings first as a backup.

Comment: I'll try the settings reset tomorrow.

Comment: Settings reset didn't help. Also, manually entering things into the registry keys above didn't help -- the UI seems to just reset it whenever it loads :(

Comment: Uh, wow. Sounds like it might be a installation issue maybe. Other than that I have literally no idea...

Comment: For the record, I came here to research this same problem. I keep having to re-add a custom look-in that I use often. Would sure be nice if VS remembered these settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can set these values programmatically inside Visual Studio for the Find and Replace dialog (for example with Visual Commander):

```
DTE.Find.FilesOfType = "*.txt";
DTE.Find.SearchPath = @"c:\temp";
```

Comment: This is interesting, but I couldn't find a way to execute these commands without installing an extension. If I were to go this route, I would probably just add a new macro to my personal AutoHotKey script to enter the paths and file types directly into the UI. I would prefer if the UI remembered them for me though (there are several combinations that I typically search.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an earlier version of VS, export the environment settings, copy the NumberOfScopes and NamedScopes* settings from the Environment_UnifiedFind section to the same section in your VS2015 settings file and then re-import settings.

Once I did this, it allowed VS2015 to start saving folder specifications for future settings exports.

Or you could try replacing this in your VS2015 export:

```
<PropertyValue name="NumberOfScopes">0</PropertyValue>
```

With this:

```
<PropertyValue name="NumberOfScopes">1</PropertyValue>
<PropertyValue name="NamedScopes&gt;0">FOLDER_SPEC_NAME&gt;SEMICOLON_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_FOLDERS&gt;{4A812F3C-7B1A-4987-9769-461F20EB25CB}</PropertyValue>
```

(Don't forget to re-import after you make the change)